# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,25000) into shape (25000)

Tags: python, matrix, error-handling

I am very new to python
Here is the problem which I have no idea how to correct. I wouldn't be surprised if it is something to do with Indentation, since I already corrected bunch of those. Another guess is the issue with matrix but I have no idea how to fix it or figure out what could be the problem.

Here is the Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-a669ca7abc3e> in <module>
    226                     rand = random_number_generator(M, I)
    227                     # volatility process paths
--> 228                     v = SRD_generate_paths(x_disc, v0, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, T, M, I, rand, 1, cho_matrix)
    229                     # index level process paths
    230                     S = H93_generate_paths(S0, r, v, 0, cho_matrix)

<ipython-input-32-a669ca7abc3e> in SRD_generate_paths(x_disc, x0, kappa, theta, sigma, T, M, I, rand, row, cho_matrix)
     90     x[0] = x0
     91     xh = np.zeros_like(x)
---> 92     xh[0] = x
     93     sdt = math.sqrt(dt)
     94     for t in range(1, M + 1):

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,25000) into shape (25000)
```

Here is the actual code. Sorry if it's too long

```
import sys
#sys.path.append('')
import math 
import string
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
from datetime import datetime
from time import time
from StochasticVolatility import H93_call_value

#Fixed Short Rate
r=0.05

# Heston (1993) Parameters
# from MS (2009), table 3
para = np.array(((0.01, 1.5, 0.15, 0.1), # panel 1
                 # (v0,kappa_v,sigma_v,rho)
                 (0.04, 0.75, 0.3, 0.1), # panel 2
                 (0.04, 1.50, 0.3, 0.1), # panel 3
                 (0.04, 1.5, 0.15, -0.5))) # panel 4
theta_v = 0.02 # lont-term variance level
S0 = 100.0 # initial index level

# General Simulation Parameters 
write = True
verbose = False
option_types = ['CALL', 'PUT'] # option types 
steps_list = [25, 50] # time steps p.a.
paths_list = [25000, 50000, 75000, 100000] # number of paths per valuation 
s_disc_list = ['Log', 'Naive'] # Euler scheme: log vs. naive
x_disc_list = ['Full Truncation', 'Partial Truncation', 'Truncation', 'Absorption', 'Reflection', 'Higham-Mao',\
               'Simple Reflection']
               # discretization schemes for SRD process
anti_paths = [False, True]
               # antithetic paths for variance reduction 
moment_matching = [False, True] 
               # random number correction (std + mean + drift)

t_list = [1.0 / 12, 1.0, 2.0] # maturity list
k_list = [90, 100, 110]      # strike list
PY1 = 0.025  # performance yardstick 1: abs. error in currency units
PY2 = 0.015  # performance yardstick 2: rel.error in decimals
runs = 5  # number of simulation runs
np.random.seed(250000)  # set RNG seed value

#
# Function for Short Rate and Volatility Processes
#

def SRD_generate_paths(x_disc, x0, kappa, theta, sigma, T, M, I, rand, row, cho_matrix):

    ''' Function to simulate Square-Root Diffusion (SRD/CIR) process.

    Parameters
    ==========
    x0: float
        initial value
    kappa: float
         mean-reversion factor
    theta: float
        long-run mean
    sigma: float
        volatility factor 
    T: float
       final date/time horizon 
    M: int 
       number of time steps 
    I: int
       number of paths
    row: int
       row number for random numbers 
    cho_matrix: NumPy array
        Cholesky matrix 

    Returns
    =======
    x: NumPy array
        simulated variance paths
    '''
    dt = T / M
    x = np.zeros ((M + 1, I), dtype=np.float)
    x[0] = x0
    xh = np.zeros_like(x)
    xh[0] = x
    sdt = math.sqrt(dt)
    for t in range(1, M + 1):
        ran = np.dot(cho_matrix, rand[:, t])
        if x_disc == 'Full Truncation':
            xh[t] = (xh[t - 1] + kappa * (theta - np.maximum(0, xh[t - 1])) * dt + np.sqrt(np.maximum(0, xh[t - 1]))\
                     * sigma * ran[row] * sdt)
            x[t] = np.maximum(0, xh[t])
        elif x_disc == 'Partial Truncation':
            xh[t] = (xh[t - 1] + kappa * (theta - xh[t- 1]) * dt\
            + np.sqrt(np.maximum(0, xh[t - 1])) * sigma * ran[row] * sdt)
            x[t] = np.maximum(0, xh[t])
        elif x_disc == 'Truncation':
            x[t] = np.maximum(0, x[t - 1]
                 + kappa * (theta - x[t - 1]) * dt +
                 np.sqrt(x[t - 1]) * sigma * ran[row] * sdt)
        elif x_disc == 'Reflection':
            xh[t] = (xh[t - 1]) + kappa * (theta - abs(xh[t - 1]) * dt +
                 np.sqrt(abs(xh[t - 1])) * sigma * ran[row] * sdt)
            x[t] = abs(xh[t])
        elif x_disc == 'Higham-Mao':
            xh[t] = (xh[t - 1] + kappa * (theta - xh[t - 1]) * dt +
                 np.sqrt(abs(xh[t - 
                                1])) * sigma * ran[row] * sdt)
            x[t] = abs(xh[t])
        elif x_disc =='Simple Reflection':
            x[t] = abs(x[t - 1] + kappa * (theta - x[t - 1]) * dt + 
                 np.sqrt(x[t - 1]) * sigma * ran[row] * sdt)
        elif x_disc == 'Absorption':
            xh[t] = (np.maximum(0, xh[t - 1])
                 + kappa * (theta - np.maximum(0, xh[t - 1])) * dt +
                 np.sqrt(np.maximum(0, xh[t - 1])) * sigma * rand[row] * sdt)
            x[t] = np.maximum(0, xh[t])
        else:
            print (x_disc)
            print ("No valid Euler scheme." ) 
            sys.exit(0)
        return x 
     #
     # Function for Heston Index Process 
     #
def H93_generate_paths(S0, r, v, row, cho_matrix):
    ''' Simulation of Heston (1993) index process.
    Parameters
    ==========
    S0: float
        initial value
    r: float
       constant short rate 
    v: NumPy array
       simulated variance paths
    row:int
        row/matrix of random number array to use
    cho_matrix: NumPy array
        Cholesky matrix

    Returns
    =======
    S:NumPy array
        simulated index level paths 
    '''
    S = np.zeros((M + 1, I), dtype=np.float)
    S[0] = S0
    bias = 0.0
    sdt = math.sqrt(dt)
    for t in range(1, M + 1, 1):
        ran = np.dot(cho_matrix, rand [:, t])
        if momatch:
            bias = np.mean(np.sqrt(v[t]) * ran[row] * sdt)
        if s_disc == 'Log':
            S[t] = S[t - 1] * np.exp((r - 0.5 * v[t]) * dt + np.sqrt(v[t]) * ran[row] *sdt - bias)
        elif s_disc == 'Naive':
            S[t] = S[t - 1] * (math.exp(r * dt) + np.sqrt(v[t]) * ran[row] * sdt - bias)
        else:
            print ("No valid Euler scheme.")
            exit(0)
    return S



def random_number_generator(M, I):
    '''Function to generate pseudo-random numbers.

    Parameters
    ==========
    M: int
       time steps
    I: int
       number of simulation paths

    Returns
    =======
    rand: NumPy array
        random number array
    '''
    if antipath:
        rand=np.random.standard_normal((2,M+1,I/2))
        rand=np.concatenate((rand,-rand),2)
    else:
        rand=np.random.standard_normal((2,M+1,I))
    if momatch:
        rand=rand/np.std(rand)
        rand=rand-np.mean(rand)
        return rand

t0 = time ()

results = pd.DataFrame()

tmpl_1 = '%4s | %3s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %5s | %5s' \
                    % ('T', 'K', 'V0', 'V0_MCS', 'err', 'rerr', 'acc1', 'acc2')
tmpl_2 = '%4.3f | %3d | %6.3f | %6.3f | %6.3f | %6.3f | %5s | %5s'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for alpha in it.product(option_types, steps_list, paths_list, s_disc_list, x_disc_list, anti_paths,moment_matching):
        print ('\n\n', alpha, '\n')
        option, M0, I, s_disc, x_disc, antipath, momatch = alpha
        for run in range(runs):
            for panel in range(4):
                # Correlation Matrix 
                v0, kappa_v, sigma_v, rho = para[panel]
                covariance_matrix = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=np.float)
                covariance_matrix[0] = [1.0, rho]
                covariance_matrix[1] = [rho, 1.0]
                cho_matrix = np.linalg.cholesky(covariance_matrix)
                if verbose:
                    print ("nResults for Panel %dn" % (panel +1))
                    print (tmpl_1)
                for T in t_list: # maturity list
                   # memory clean-up
                    v, S, rand, h = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
                    M = int(M0 * T) # number of total time steps 
                    dt = T / M # time interval in years 
                    # random numbers
                    rand = random_number_generator(M, I)
                    # volatility process paths 
                    v = SRD_generate_paths(x_disc, v0, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, T, M, I, rand, 1, cho_matrix)
                    # index level process paths
                    S = H93_generate_paths(S0, r, v, 0, cho_matrix)
                for K in k_list:
                 # European option values   
                    B0T = math.exp(-r * T) # discount factor 
                # European call option value (semi-analytical)
                    C0 = H93_call_value(S0, K, T, r, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, rho, v0)
                    P0 = C0 + K + B0T - S0
                    if option is 'PUT':

                    # benchmark value
                        V0 = P0
                    # inner value matrix put
                        h = np.matrix(K - S, 0)
                    elif option is 'CALL':
                        # benchmark value
                        V0 = C0
                        # inner value matrix call 
                        h = np.maximum(S - K, 0)
                    else:
                        print ("No valid option type.")
                        sys.exit(0)
                    pv = B0T * h[-1] # present value vector 
                    V0_MCS = np.sum(pv) / I  # MCS estimator
                    SE = np.std(pv) / math.sqrt(I)
                    # standard error 
                    error = V0_MCS - V0
                    real_error = (V0_MCS - V0) / V0
                    PY1_acc = abs(error) < PY1
                    PY2_acc = abs(real_error) < PY2
                    res = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': datetime.now(), 
                        '0type': option, 'runs': runs, 'steps': M0, 
                         'paths': I, 'index_disc': s_disc, 
                          'var_disc': x_disc, 'anti_paths': antipath,     
                          'moment_matching': momatch, 'panel': panel,
                          'maturity': T, 'strike': K, 'value': V0,
                          'MCS_est': V0_MCS, 'SE': SE, 'error': error, 
                          'real_error': real_error, 'PY1': PY1, 'PY2': PY2,
                          'PY1_acc': PY1_acc, 'PY2_acc': PY2_acc,
                          'PY_acc': PY1_acc or PY2_acc}, index=[0,])

                    if verbose:
                        print (tmpl_2 % (T, K, V0, V0_MCS, error, real_error, PY1_acc, PY2_acc))

                    results = results.append(res, ignore_index=True)
        if write:
            d = str(datetime.now ().replace(microsecond=0))
            d = d.translate(string.maketrans("-:", "_ _"))
            h5= pd.HDFStore('10_mcs/mcs_european_%s_%s.h5' % (d[:10], d[11:]), 'w')
            h5['results'] = results
            h5.close()
    print ("Total time in minutes %8.2f" % ((time() - t0) / 60))
```

Comment: please include the code where you called the function

Comment: edited, added whole code

Answer (score 0):

Because `xh[0].shape=(25000,)`, it's actually a 1D array with 25000 zeros. While `x` has a shape of `(3,25000)`, I guess, the values cannot be assigned.

Comment: I am new to coding, so I kinda understand what you saying but still don't know how to correct the issue at hand.